# Vanila JS counter

Tags: javascript

Trying to get all four counters to finish at the same time.
e.g.
Counter four should stay at zero until counter three reaches value of 14, then switch to 1.
Counter one should increment by following counter two and three.

https://jsfiddle.net/IhaveVoicesinMyhead/0j9q1b85/2/#&togetherjs=f3xchiJM9f

```js
const counter = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
const speed = 200;

counter.forEach(counter => {
  const updateCount = () => {
    const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
    const count = +counter.innerText;

    const increment = target / speed;

    if (count < target) {
      counter.innerText = Math.ceil(count + increment);
      setTimeout(updateCount, 80);
    } else {
      count.innerText = target;
    }


  }

  updateCount();
});
```

```css
.counters {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.counters .container-max-width {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.counters .container-max-width .counter {
  font-size: 3.25em;
}

.counters .container-max-width span {
  color: #848484;
  padding: 0;
}

.counters .container-inner-width {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  padding: 85px 0 85px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="counters">
  <div class="container-max-width">
    <div class="container-inner-width">
      <div>
        <div class="counter counter-one" data-target="4">0</div>
        <span>counter one</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="counter counter-two" data-target="10">0</div>
        <span>counter two</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="counter counter-three" data-target="15">0</div>
        <span>counter three</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="counter counter-four" data-target="1">0</div>
        <span>counter four</span>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is `Math.ceil`. You are rounding up the number after each increment. That makes all counters increase more then the expected `increment`, and all by different amount. If you remove `Math.ceil` and let the numbers remain decimals, all counters will end at the same time. One solution is to keep the real number in a variable, and print the rounded number as text in HTML, instead of using the HTML text to store your number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how you can create multiple timers that all end at the same time. I separated the logic behind it (countUp()) from the view (createTimer()), so you should be able to adapt the countUp() function to whatever needs you have. Just give it your desired final value, how long you want it to execute (in ms), and what you want it to do at each step.

```js
const counter1 = document.getElementById('counter1')
const counter2 = document.getElementById('counter1')

function countUp({ to, onStep, duration, _currentValue = 0 }) {
  onStep(_currentValue)
  if (_currentValue === to) return
  setTimeout(() => {
    countUp({ to, onStep,duration, _currentValue: _currentValue + 1 })
  }, duration / to)
}

function createTimer(to) {
  const timerEl = document.createElement('div')
  document.body.appendChild(timerEl)
  const onStep = currentValue => {
    timerEl.innerText = currentValue
  }
  countUp({ to, duration: 3000, onStep })
}

createTimer(1)
createTimer(10)
createTimer(20)
```

Note that this doesn't account for setTimeout() drift (setTimeout doesn't always execute the callback as soon as the you asked it to), so you shouldn't use this solution for longer-lasting or very precise timers. You can add some more math to it if you want to account for drift.